# Using Views to categorize results

Tags: views

I have a view which is returning integers. Instead of presenting the actual values, I'd like to replace them with the name of a category. For example, all of smaller numbers (<100) are to be returned as "low", mid-range results (101 - 999) will say "moderate," and large values (>1000) to read as "large". Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views Conditional (https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional) which has stable releases for D7 and D8 will do this.

IF/ELSE is readily apparent when using this module. To achieve what I desired, I created two conditional fields:

Views: Views Conditional (If field_number is Less than 100, output Low, else output Moderate)

and

Views: Views Conditional (If field_number is Greater than 1000, output Large, else output [views_conditional] )

Then exclude the first conditional field from display.